# Timer interrupt doesn't run it's service routine in atmel simulation

Tags: assembly, interrupt, avr, atmel

I use 'Step Into' for line to line debugging of app. I want to use Timer1 overflow interrupt, the timer overflows but the interrupt doesn't run it's service routine. What's problem?

```
.INCLUDE "M32DEF.inc"
.ORG 0
    JMP MAIN

.ORG 0x12
    JMP TOV_1

.ORG 0x100
MAIN:   
    LDI R16, 0xFF
    OUT TCNT1H, R16
    LDI R16, 0xF0
    OUT TCNT1L, R16

    ;START Timer1
    LDI R16, 0
    OUT TCCR1A, R16
    LDI R16, 1
    OUT TCCR1B, R16

    ;Init Timer1 Interrupt
    LDI R16, (1<<TOIE1)
    OUT TIMSK, R16
    SEI

A:
    RJMP A

.ORG 0x200
TOV_1:
    INC R20
    RETI
```

Answer (score 1):

Your program doesn't initialize the stack pointer before using interrupts.

The AVR depends on the stack pointer in order to know where to put the return address at which program execution will continue after the `RETI`.
The stack pointer is usually initialized to point to the last memory location (stack grows 'backwards') by setting stack pointer high `SPH` and low registers `SPL` to `RAMEND`.
The following code snippet is taken from the [ATmega32 datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc2503.pdf) page 45.

> ```
> RESET:   ldi   r16,high(RAMEND) ; Main program start
>          out   SPH,r16          ; Set Stack Pointer to top of RAM
>          ldi   r16,low(RAMEND)
>          out   SPL,r16
>          sei
> ```

Put this snippet to where currently your `SEI` is and your program should be able to jump into and return from ISRs.

Comment: I initialize stack but not mentioned in my question